# ZPL- Design Label

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I am new to ZPL Programming. Can someone tell me whats wrong with me ZPL program.

I have to design the following label: https://i.stack.imgur.com/60UHl.png
But up till now I have achieved this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xL285.png

But when I add another grid I lost the last barcode: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1vb4.png

Is there something wrong with my code or can someone help me appending the upper two grids.

Here's my code:

```
^XA

^FX Fourth section (the two boxes on the bottom). ^FO50,50^GB900,520,3^FS

^FO50,400^GB900,1,2^FS

^CF0,40 ^FO100,440^FDCtr. X34B-1^FS ^FO100,510^FDCtr. X34B-1^FS

^CF0,40 ^FO510,440^FDCtr. X34B-1^FS ^FO510,510^FDCtr. X34B-1^FS

^FX Fourth section (the two boxes on the bottom). ^FO50,570^GB900,150,3^FS ^FO500,570^GB1,150,3^FS ^FO500,650^GB450,1,2^FS ^CF0,40 ^FO100,590^FDCtr. X34B-1^FS ^FO100,630^FDCtr. X34B-1^FS

^CF0,40 ^FO510,590^FDCtr. X34B-1^FS ^FO510,670^FDCtr. X34B-1^FS

^FX Fourth section (the two boxes on the bottom). ^FO50,720^GB900,150,3^FS

^FX Bar code with height of 100 dots ^FO370,735 ^BCN,120,N,N,N,N ^BY2,3; ^FD>;129393933939839489383 ^FS

^CF1,30 ^FO20,900^FDPotatoes^FS ^FO20,940^FDRPC^FS ^FO20,980^FDNorkotah^FS ^FO20,1010^FDRPC HEB^FS

^FO400,900^FDQTY: 40^FS

^FO800,900^FD08/11/2020^FS ^BY3,3,120 ^FO400,970^BC^FD1293939339^FS

^CF1,30 ^FO20,1200^FDPotatoes^FS ^FO20,1240^FDRPC^FS ^FO20,1280^FDNorkotah^FS ^FO20,1320^FDRPC HEB^FS

^FO400,1200^FDQTY: 40^FS

^FO800,1200^FD08/11/2020^FS ^BY3,3,120 ^FO400,1250^BC^FD1293939339^FS

^XZ
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit..i have recently started using it after such a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely the source of your problems:

```
^FX Fourth section (the two boxes on the bottom). ^FO50,50^GB900,520,3^FS
```

You need to add `^FS` to the end of each of your comments.  Best practice is to put the comments on their own lines:

```
^FX Fourth section (the two boxes on the bottom).^FS
^FO50,50^GB900,520,3^FS
```

Comment: Yes exactly my comments were making an issue for me. Thank you